# Unable to run integration tests when upgrading grails from version 5 to 6 - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':integrationTest'

Tags: gradle, grails

We are upgrading a grails 5.2 application to grails 6. The application boots up fine, anf the unit tests are also running, however when running integration tests, we are getting following error:

```
%./gradlew integrationTest --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':integrationTest'.
> Could not create task ':mergeTestReports'.
   > 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.getDestinationDirectory()'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':integrationTest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:71)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getFinalizedBy(LocalTaskNode.java:165)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:133)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:186)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:150)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addEntryTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:146)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:45)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.lambda$select$0(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:160)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:147)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:39)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareTaskExecution(VintageBuildModelController.java:111)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.doBuildStages(VintageBuildModelController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.scheduleRequestedTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:120)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$2(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withModelOrThrow$5(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withModel(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withModelOrThrow(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:140)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:111)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$1.run(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:113)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.lambda$prepareTaskGraph$0(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:110)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withState(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:236)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.prepareTaskGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:83)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewTaskGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:104)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:91)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:154)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':mergeTestReports'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.taskCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:715)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.access$600(DefaultTaskContainer.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.domainObjectCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:707)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:948)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.access$1401(DefaultTaskContainer.java:654)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider$1.run(DefaultTaskContainer.java:680)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultTaskContainer.java:676)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:929)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.getOrNull(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.findByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:295)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.findByName(DefaultTaskContainer.java:558)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.findByPath(DefaultTaskContainer.java:465)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.getByPath(DefaultTaskContainer.java:488)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.resolveTask(DefaultTaskContainer.java:483)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultTaskDependency.java:139)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:69)
        ... 133 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.getDestinationDirectory()'
        at org.grails.gradle.plugin.core.IntegrationTestGradlePlugin$_apply_closure5.doCall(IntegrationTestGradlePlugin.groovy:87)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithManyActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:329)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:260)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:254)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:944)
        ... 159 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Here are the dependencies in my application in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.grails:grails-core")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-logging")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-plugin-rest")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-plugin-services")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings")
    implementation("org.grails:grails-web-boot")
    implementation("org.grails.plugins:views-json")
    implementation("org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    compileOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy")
    console("org.grails:grails-console")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    runtimeOnly("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
    runtimeOnly("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc")
    runtimeOnly("org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.2.1-b05")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy")
    testImplementation("org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support")
    testImplementation("org.grails:views-json-testing-support")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")

    //custom added dependencies
    implementation "com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus:7.14.0"
    implementation "com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.23.0"
    implementation "com.logentries:logentries-appender:1.1.38"
    implementation "com.opencsv:opencsv:5.7.1"
    implementation "net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5"
    implementation "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.4"
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:4.1.2"
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2"
    implementation "org.apache.tika:tika-core:2.7.0"
    implementation "org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.9"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:mongodb"
    implementation "org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.3"
    implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.3"
    implementation platform("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.18.3")
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:mongodb"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:spock"
}
```

seems like we are missing a dependency but not sure what exactly is causing the integration test to not run. Would really appreciate any suggestion/help to resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: From the Gradle output, it appears you are using Gradle Wrapper version 7.2 instead of 7.6.2 which is the default for Grails 6.0.0

Comment: That was it, thank you so much, I wouldn't have been able to figure this one out! Thanks again, if you post it an an answer I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Gradle output you shared, it appears you are using Gradle Wrapper version 7.2 instead of 7.6.2 which is the default for Grails 6.0.0 applications. I think this is likely the source of your problem.